# Adding buttons programmatically to stackView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I've tried to add buttons dynamically/programmatically in UIStackView that I've built with interface builder but they failed to show up when I run the application. The number of buttons that's supposed to be added ranging normally from 4-6. Can you guys tell me what's wrong with the code

[image: 5 buttons] 
[image: 4 buttons] 
[image: code]

Comment: Probably some sizing issues.

Comment: I've already set the size & constraint of the stackView using the Interface Builder. @MojtabaHosseini

Comment: Do not add Solved to title.

Answer (score 17):

@Nowonder I just recreate what you are trying to achieve. The following are the steps.

1. Add a `UIStackView` in viewController from `Interface Builder` and add required constraints.
2. Add the following code.

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      let button = UIButton()
      button.setTitle("btn 1", for: .normal)
      button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
      button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

      let button2 = UIButton()
      button2.setTitle("btn 2", for: .normal)
      button2.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
      button2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

      let button3 = UIButton()
      button3.setTitle("btn 3", for: .normal)
      button3.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
      button3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

      buttonStackView.alignment = .fill
      buttonStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
      buttonStackView.spacing = 8.0

      buttonStackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
      buttonStackView.addArrangedSubview(button2)
      buttonStackView.addArrangedSubview(button3)  

   }
   ```

Following is the outcome.
[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do few more steps before the button will start showing up.

1. Add the stack view to current view's subviews

   ```
   view.addSubview(buttonStackView)
   ```
2. Now each of these views buttons, as well as the stackView, needs to set the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false.

   ```
   button1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   button2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   buttonStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   ```
3. Now set the stackView contraints

   ```
   NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
       buttonStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
       buttonStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
       buttonStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
       buttonStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)])
   ```
4. You will need to provide the constraints, or can override the intrinsic size of stackView.

   ```
    override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize
    {
      return CGSizeMake(200, 40)
    }
   ```

As `UILabel` have the intrinsic size and so, the button will show, if not you will have to set the constraints for them also to be safe.

Comment: The buttons eventually show up when I specify the type of the buttons. However, I'll try your method later

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED!

The button showed up when I set the type of the button with the instance method init(type:)